# Is there a solution to this oracle APEX error?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I have been working on a school project that requires me to create a simple application in Oracle APEX. I'm at a step that instructs me to create a page that is going to be a form. On the very last step of creating the form, I repeatedly get these errors: ORA-20001: Unable to create query and update page. ORA-20001: Error creating page name="employees Report" id="3" ORA-00001: unique constraint (APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_STEPS_PK) violated

I've tried countlessly to find a solution but so far I'm still stuck. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the primary key, but - if I had to guess - I'd say it is a page number. So: start over. When the Wizard asks you which page number you want to create, instead of "id = 3" (which you posted in the question), overtype it to e.g. 10. Also, try to give that page another name (such as "frm_employees").

---

Also, consider creating a *report with a form* instead of just a form. That wizard will create

- interactive report (you'd select the `employees` table) which lets you view data stored in the table

  - at the beginning of each row, there's an icon you can use to modify/delete data
  - there's the CREATE button which - when pushed - leads you to a ...
- ... **form** page (you're supposed to create)